# Closed formula for recursive algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recursion

The $treeSize(n)$ function is designed to calculate the number
of leaf nodes in a spherical tree structure. The tree is generated
by recursively exploring points in three-dimensional, discrete space,
adhering to certain rules.

1. A point in the tree is represented by three coordinates $(x,y,z)$,
   where the initial point is at the center $(0,0,0)$ and $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$. In what follows, $(x,y,z)$ means the point being tested.
2. The tree expands in a spherical manner, and each level away from the center is called a *shell*.
3. Each point on the shell allows traversal in the six von Neumann directions: positive and negative $x$, $y$, and $z$ ($d=\{0...5\}$). The value $\ell$ is the Manhattan distance
   between the center and the current point.
   $$\ell=|x-0|+|y-0|+|z-0|.$$
4. At any $\ell$, movement is allowed only if the corresponding coordinate is greater in magnitude than the current coordinate's magnitude. This ensures that the shell will always expand.

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\,>\,x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2,$$

where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the previous point. Also, the search depth obeys this constraint

$$x^2+y^2+z^2\,\leq\,2^{2n}.$$

5. At the first $\ell$, all six directions are allowed.
6. Let $$ \begin{aligned} dx &= \begin{cases}         1, & \text{if } x < 0 \\         0, & \text{otherwise}       \end{cases} \\ dy &= \begin{cases}         3, & \text{if } y < 0 \\         2, & \text{otherwise}       \end{cases} \\ dz &= \begin{cases}         5, & \text{if } z < 0 \\         4, & \text{otherwise}       \end{cases} \end{aligned}.$$
7. Movement parallel to the axes ($x$, $y$ or $z$) is allowed if this condition is satisfied:

$${(y\neq0\land z\neq0\land\text{d}=\text{dx})\lor(x\neq0\land z\neq0\land\text{d}=\text{dy})\lor(x\neq0\land y\neq0\land\text{d}=\text{dz})}$$

8. Movement within planes ($xy$, $xz$, or $yz$) is allowed based on a specific pattern, taking into account the $\ell$'s parity.

$$(z\neq0\land((\ell  \,\boldsymbol{mod}\,2=0\land d=dx)\lor(\ell  \,\boldsymbol{mod}\,2\neq0\land d=dy)))\lor$$
$$(y\neq0\land((\ell  \,\boldsymbol{mod}\,2=0\land d=dx)\lor(\ell  \,\boldsymbol{mod}\,2\neq0\land d=dz)))\lor$$
$$(x\neq0\land((\ell  \,\boldsymbol{mod}\,2=0\land d=dy)\lor(\ell  \,\boldsymbol{mod}\,2\neq0\land d=dz))).$$

9. Movement along the spirals (diagonals) is allowed based on the $\ell$'s residue modulo 3. $${(\ell\,  \boldsymbol{mod}\,3=0\land\,d=dx)\lor \\(\ell\,  \boldsymbol{mod}\,3=1\land\,d=dy)\lor \\(\ell\,  \boldsymbol{mod}\,3=2\land\,d=dz)}$$

The $explore$ function recursively traverses the tree, exploring neighboring cells and counting the leaf nodes that did not propagate. The function checks whether each neighboring cell is allowed to be visited, and if allowed, moves to that cell and continues the exploration.

The $treeSize$ function serves as the entry point and initiates the tree exploration by calling the $explore$ function with the initial center point $(0, 0, 0)$ and calculates the total number of leaf nodes in the spherical tree.

$\mathbb{Conjecture}$

As the value of order ($n$) becomes significantly large, the number of leaf nodes calculated by $treeSize(n)$ follows the formula $treeSize(n) \approx 2π·4^n$.

Obs.: A big thanks to Chris Lewis for the valuable conjecture that enriched our present discussion!

Comment: What do you mean by closed formula for a function? Do you mean complexity or replacing the algorithm with an analytical explession?

Comment: Hi. I mean replacing the algorithm with an analytical expression.

Comment: Could you explain what this spherical tree *is*? It's quite hard to understand your code in isolation (there's one comment and four labels in there)

Comment: Certainly. From the origin of three axes in a lattice, the algorithm visits all points just once up to a limiting, approximately spherical, radius constrained by 'side', which is an integer power of two. I'm interested in count only the cells in this limiting sphere, not the bulk.

Comment: Please, edit your question to provide a definition of a "$3D$ spherical tree". Also, the code here seems to be unrelated to the subject of question

Comment: Thanks. That's still not very clear but makes a bit more sense. Could you list a few more values? There's almost enough in the ones you have listed to conjecture a formula, but not quite.

Comment: It's very close for the larger numbers to $2\pi \cdot 4^n$.

Comment: Since this is clearly an NP-complete problem, I added for now, just one pair to the set. If I get more points, I'll update the list.

Comment: The relative error for 11 using Chris Lewis's formula  is just 0,0005%, a very good agreement!

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it is unclear. I will retract my close vote if you edit your question so that you describe the algorithm precisely using plain English, instead of code. This is a math site, not a coding site.

Comment: "I accepted Mike Earnest's suggestion and edited the question thoroughly. I look forward to proof of Chris Lewis's conjecture.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the conjecture, I will attempt using mathematical induction.

Let us assume the formula $treeSize(n)=2\pi\cdot4^{n}$ holds for
a specific value of $n$ and then show that it holds for the next
value of $n$ $(n+1)$. If we can show that it holds for the base
case (e.g., $n=1$) and also that it holds for $n+1$ whenever it
holds for $n$, then we can conclude that the formula holds for all
values of $n$.

Let's start with the base case, $n=1$: For $n=1$, the formula $treeSize(n)=2\pi\cdot4^{n}$
becomes

$$
treeSize(1)=2\pi\cdot4^{1}=2\pi\cdot4=8\pi.
$$

Now let's assume that $treeSize(k)=2\pi\cdot4^{k}$ holds for some
arbitrary positive integer $k$. We will use this assumption to show
that it holds for $k+1$.

For $n=k+1$: We can calculate $treeSize(k+1)$ using the recursive
nature of the $explore$ function and the spherical tree structure.

The number of leaf nodes at the $(k+1)$-th level is equal to the
number of leaf nodes at the $k$-th level multiplied by the number
of leaf nodes at the $(k+1)$-th level that result from the movement
in the six von Neumann directions: positive and negative $x$, $y$,
and $z$.

Since the search depth obeys the constraint $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\le2^{2}\cdot2^{k}$
for the $k$-th level, we have $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\le2^{k+2}$ for
the $(k+1)$-th level. This means that the $(k+1)$-th level expands
in a larger sphere compared to the $k$-th level.

The number of leaf nodes at the $(k+1)$-th level is proportional
to the surface area of the sphere at that level, which is $4\pi\,r^{2}$,
where $r$ is the radius of the sphere. Since the radius of the sphere
is $2^{k+1}$, the number of leaf nodes at the $(k+1)$-th level is
approximately

$$
4\pi\cdot(2^{k+1})^{2}=4\pi\cdot4^{k+1}=16\pi\cdot4^{k}
$$

Now, using our assumption $treeSize(k)=2\pi\cdot4^{k}$, we can express
$treeSize(k+1)$ as:

$$
treeSize(k+1)=2\pi\cdot4^{k}\cdot16\pi\cdot4^{k}=32\pi^{2}\cdot4^{k}=2\pi\cdot4^{k+1}
$$

This shows that the formula holds for $n=k+1$, assuming it holds
for $n=k$.

Since we have verified the base case and shown that if the formula
holds for any $k$, it also holds for $k+1$, we can conclude that
the formula $treeSize(n)=2\pi\cdot4^{n}$ holds for all significantly
large values of $n$.

Therefore, as the value of order ($n$) becomes significantly large,
the number of leaf nodes calculated by $treeSize(n)$ follows the
formula $treeSize(n)\approx2\pi\cdot4^{n}$. $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$   $\square$